# How can I extract the start and end of multiple ranges from a column?

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, range, key-value, record

I have a database where a column called StatusMotor is so:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Date-time      + MotorStatus+
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 03-02-20 18:35 + Start      +  
+ 03-02-20 18:35 + Start      +
+ 03-02-20 18:36 + Start      +
+ 03-02-20 18:35 + Start      +
+ 03-02-20 18:36 + Start      +
+ 03-02-20 18:36 + Start      +
+ 03-02-20 18:36 + Stop       +
+ 03-02-20 18:36 + Stop       +
+ 03-02-20 18:36 + Stop       +
+ 03-02-20 18:36 + Standby    + 
+ 03-02-20 18:37 + Standby    +
+ 03-02-20 18:37 + Start      +
+ ...            + ....
```

I have three status **(START, STOP, STAND BY)** and i **would extract moments when Motor works**:

the date-time when i have **1st Start or Start after a Stop and Standby**,
and when I have **last start before a Stop or Standby**.

```
select DateTime, MotorStatus
from TableName 
Where MotorStatus like 'Start' and...
```

I don't know what condition i put to have this range.
How i could to do?

Comment: Your datatime values have duplicates with different statuses, and there is no data which may set the rows ordering in thу table (physical posession cannot be used - it does not exist in a table). The task is unsolvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, and on MySQL 8+ we can use the difference in row numbers method here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MotorStatus ORDER BY DateTime) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT MIN(DateTime) AS start, MAX(DateTime) AS `end`
FROM cte
WHERE MotorStatus = 'Start'
GROUP BY rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY start;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: The query is not deterministic: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae48a9ba450df9836a027ca0e0c1f451